# Multiple update and deletes in multiple tables SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables namely City, Location, Customer and Shop. The person who designed this DB has made the primary key auto-incremented. As a result, there are redundant data in the DB overtime. I'm trying to clean the database but it is taking really long time to update and delete the rows.  The sample of the tables looks like below:

```
Table 1: City: ID_city(PK)
| City      | ID_City |
|-----------|---------|
| Chennai   | 1       |
| Benagluru | 2       |
| Chennai   | 3       |
| Delhi     | 4       |
| Chennai   | 5       |
| Bengaluru | 6       |

Table 2: Location: ID_Location(PK), ID_City(FK)
| Zip  | ID_location        | ID_City |
|------|--------------------|---------|
| 0001 | 1                  | 1       |
| 0011 | 2                  | 2       |
| 0002 | 3                  | 1       |
| 0021 | 4                  | 3       |
| 0003 | 5                  | 1       |
| 0012 | 6                  | 2       |
| 0001 | 7 (duplicate of 1) | 1       |

Table 3: Customer: Cust_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)
| Cust_ID | ID_location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 3           |
| 3       | 5           |
| 4       | 2           |
| 5       | 7           |

Table 4: Shop: Shop_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)
| Shop_ID | ID_location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 2           |
| 3       | 6           |
| 4       | 3           |
| 5       | 7           |
```

**Expected table:**

```
Table 1: City: ID_city(PK)
| City      | ID_City |
|-----------|---------|
| Chennai   | 1       |
| Benagluru | 2       |
| Delhi     | 4       |

Table 2: Location: ID_Location(PK), ID_City(FK)
| Zip  | ID_Location | ID_City |
|------|-------------|---------|
| 0001 | 1           | 1       |
| 0011 | 2           | 2       |
| 0002 | 3           | 1       |
| 0021 | 4           | 1       |
| 0003 | 5           | 1       |
| 0012 | 6           | 2       |

Table  3: Customer: Cust_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)
| Cust_ID | ID_Location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 3           |
| 3       | 5           |
| 4       | 2           |
| 5       | 1           |

Table 4: Shop: Shop_ID(PK), ID_Location(FK)
| Shop_ID | ID_Location |
|---------|-------------|
| 1       | 1           |
| 2       | 2           |
| 3       | 6           |
| 4       | 3           |
| 5       | 1           |
```

As you see, there are duplicate records everywhere and it takes 3 update statements(using join) and 2 delete statements to delete 1 duplicate city. 
Is there a way to reduce the number of SQL statements to carryout this task?

The queries I wrote are:

1. update  Customer set ID_location = 1 where Cust_ID = 5
2. update Shop set ID_location = 1 where Shop_ID = 5
3. delete from location where ID_location = 7
4. update Location set ID_City = 1 where ID_City = 3 or ID_City = 5
5. delete from City where ID_Location = 3 or ID_Location = 5

This is to delete 1 duplicate City and there are around 1300 duplicates in City table. Is there an easy way to check for duplicates, update and eventually delete?

Comment: Can you reformat your data examples please

Comment: What do you mean with takes a lot of time? (a) Time to write the queries or (b) time to execute them. IF (a), no you can't do less except if you are writing them per invalid line. But I don't see how writing 6 queries is an issue. IF (b) then this is more a query tuning question and you should show the query's you've written and tell us something about the number of rows in the tables.

Comment: @SamSegers its the time to exceute them. I have around 9,000 rows in City table, 16000+ rows in location table, 48,000+ rows in Customer table, 4000+ rows in Shop table.

Comment: For me your updated question is contradictory to previous comment. You are going to write all query's one by one? While you probably just want to have one query per operation/table to do all changes? The queries in your updated question are more or less optimal due to their simplicity.

Comment: @SamSegers sorry, I meant it is time consuming to write all queries one by one. I was wondering if all these are done in one query. Probably something similar to a for loop in other languages to search for duplicates, make update and to delete.

Comment: Cannot be right as there is no ID_City = 3 in the fix

Comment: @Paparazzi that is because 3 is a duplicate of 1.  He can, and wants to, remove it.  Along with city Id 5 which is again a duplicate.

Comment: @user7396598 Check the edit history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update an entire table in one time based on conditions. Which in your case is the existence of another row with duplicate values.

```
-- (1) UPDATE DUPLICATE CITIES ON LOCATION
UPDATE l SET l.Id_City = mstr.Id_City
-- SELECT c.Id_City oldId, mstr.Id_City newId  -- Check this for your convenience
FROM [Location] l
    INNER JOIN City c ON c.Id_City = l.Id_City 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT City, MIN(Id_City) Id_City -- KEEP FIRST ONLY
        FROM City
        GROUP BY City
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    ) mstr ON mstr.City = c.City
        AND mstr.Id_City < Id_City

-- (2) DELETE DUPLICATE CITIES
DELETE c
-- SELECT c.Id_City oldId, mstr.Id_City newId  -- Check this for your convenience
FROM City c
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT City, MIN(Id_City) Id_City -- KEEP FIRST ONLY
        FROM City
        GROUP BY City
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    ) mstr ON mstr.City = c.City
        AND mstr.Id_City < Id_City

-- ...
```

The rest of the queries can be made analog to these examples

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but should be able to get it to work from here

```
declare @City table (ID_city int primary key, City varchar(10));
insert into  @city values 
       (1, 'Chennai')
     , (2, 'Benagluru')
     , (3, 'Chennai')
     , (4, 'Delhi')
     , (5, 'Chennai')
     , (6, 'Benagluru');
--select * from @city c order by c.City, c.ID_city;

declare @Location table (ID_Location int primary key, ID_City int, zip char(4))
insert into @Location values 
       (1, 1, '0001') 
     , (2, 2, '0011')
     , (3, 1, '0002')
     , (4, 3, '0021')
     , (5, 1, '0003')
     , (6, 2, '0012')
     , (7, 1, '0001');  --duplicate
--select * from @Location l order by l.ID_Location;

declare @Customer table (Cust_ID int primary key, ID_Location int)
insert into @Customer values
       (1, 1)
     , (2, 3)
     , (3, 5)
     , (4, 2)
     , (5, 7);
--select * from @Customer;

declare @Shop table (Shop_ID int primary key, ID_Location int) 
insert into @Shop values 
       (1, 1)
     , (2, 2)
     , (3, 6)
     , (4, 3)
     , (5, 7);
--select * from @Shop s order by s.Shop_ID;

 declare @LocationMap table (ID_Location int primary key, ID_City int, zip char(4), cnt int, rn int)
 insert into @LocationMap
 select l.* 
      , count(*)     over (partition by zip) as cnt 
      , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by zip order by ID_Location) as rn 
   from @Location l;
--select * from @LocationMap where cnt > 1 order by zip, rn;

declare @CityMap table (ID_city int primary key, City varchar(10), cnt int, rn int)
insert into @CityMap 
select c.* 
     , count(*)     over (partition by City) as cnt 
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by City order by City, ID_city) as rn 
 from @City c;
--select * from @CityMap m where m.cnt > 1 order by m.City, m.ID_city;

update c 
set c.ID_Location = f.ID_Location
from @Customer c
join @LocationMap m 
  on m.ID_Location = c.ID_Location
 and m.rn > 1
join @LocationMap f 
  on f.ID_City = m.ID_City
 and m.rn = 1; 
select c.* from @Customer c order by c.Cust_ID

update s 
set s.ID_Location = f.ID_Location
from @shop s 
join @LocationMap m 
  on m.ID_Location = s.ID_Location
 and m.rn > 1
join @LocationMap f 
  on f.zip = m.zip 
 and m.rn = 1; 
select s.* from @shop s order by s.Shop_ID;

--select l.* from @Location l order by l.ID_Location;
update l 
set l.ID_City = f.ID_City
from @Location l
join @CityMap m 
  on m.ID_city = l.ID_City 
 and m.rn > 1
join @CityMap f 
  on f.City = m.City
 and f.rn = 1; 
select l.* from @Location l order by l.ID_Location;

 delete l 
 from @Location l 
 join @LocationMap m
   on l.ID_Location = m.ID_Location 
  and m.rn > 1;
select * from @Location l order by l.ID_Location;

 delete c 
 from @City c
 join @CityMap m
   on c.ID_city = m.ID_city 
  and m.rn > 1;
select * from @City c order by c.ID_city;
```